# Milk in fermented bread dough

Tags: bread, milk, sourdough, fermentation

I would like to ask if the role of milk in bread dough fermentation, is to increase the population of microorganisms similarly present in sourdough bread? If so, can it be said that this kind of bread recipe comes close to sourdough bread?

Comment: Please clarify: What do you mean by fermentation? What kind of dough? What time frame?

Comment: @Stephie I do not know what specific kind of dough it would be: flour, yeast, salt, sugar, optional spice and nuts. Time frame is 12-20 hours at room temperature.

Answer (score 1):

I put milk in yeast bread some of the time because it results in different taste and texture than using water. Nothing to do with critters, which will almost all be yeast from the yeast (and their great-grand-yeasts), rather than anything specific to the milk.